# opendj user a different attribute rather than default ds-pwp-account-disabled to track user's status?

Tags: opendj

Is there a way to user a different rather than ds-pwp-account-disabled attribute to track user's status ?

As I know it's possible to track user's last login time with a customized attribute.  I'm wondering is there a similar setting for user status ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the only attribute that OpenDJ uses and manages for disabling an account is the ds-pwp-account-disabled boolean.